# Understanding the pointcut and accessing the annotation parameter in advice

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj, spring-aop

Could someone please help me understand the below pointcut in aspectj?

This pointcut works for annotation `@DynamicValue` but how it works is confusing.

Below is my custom annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface DynamicValue {
String lookupName() default "";
}
```

My class using the annotation:

```
com.package.sample;
Class SampleA{

@DynamicValue("Hello")
public String greet;

//getters & setters

}
```

And the aspect containing pointcut:

```
@Aspect
@Configurable
@Component
public class DynamicValueAspect
{

@Pointcut("get(@com.sample.aspect.DynamicValue java.lang.String com.package.sample..*.*)")
public void isDynamicValue() {}

@Around("isDynamicValue()")
public void getLocalized(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Annotation called");
//How can I access the parameter in annotation here 
//i.e "Hello" from the @DynamicValue("Hello")
}
```

Is the pointcut correct, and will it work wherever I use the `@DynamicValue` annotation?

Also I would like to know how to access the Annotation Parameter in the advice?

Comment: Please next time provide sample code which actually compiles. `com.package.sample` is an illegal package name in Java because `package` is a reserved word.

Comment: @kriegaex Thank you, I'll take care of that next time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface DynamicValue {
    String lookupName() default "";
}
```

**Driver application with an annotated member:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    @DynamicValue(lookupName = "foobar")
    public String greet;
    public String anotherMember;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        application.greet = "world";
        application.anotherMember = "Another member";
        application.sayHello();
    }

    private void sayHello() {
        System.out.println(anotherMember);
        System.out.println("Hello " + greet);
    }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import de.scrum_master.app.DynamicValue;

@Aspect
@Configurable
@Component
public class DynamicValueAspect {
    @Pointcut("get(String de.scrum_master.app..*) && @annotation(dynamicValue)")
    public void isDynamicValue(DynamicValue dynamicValue) {}

    @Around("isDynamicValue(dynamicValue)")
    public Object getLocalized(DynamicValue dynamicValue, ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        System.out.println("    " + dynamicValue);
        return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
Another member
get(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.greet)
    @de.scrum_master.app.DynamicValue(lookupName=foobar)
Hello world
```

By the way, a `@Before` advice is sufficient if you do not want to change the result for `get()`. For just printing something `@Around` is overkill.

---

Because OP asked if it is possible to limit pointcut matching to a certain primitive type like `int`, both capturing real primitives and the boxed type `Integer`, I am going to show a variant doing just that. As as I said earlier, if there is not need to manipulate the value returned by the field accessor pointcut, there is no need to use `@Around` either. We just use `@AfterReturning` because it has an optional `returning` parameter by means of which we can bind the actual return value to an advice parameter. If then we choose something other than `Object` for that advice parameter - in this case we just use `int` - we get what was asked for.

So let us add two annotated parameters typed `int` and `Integer` to the original code:

**Driver application with annotated members:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    @DynamicValue(lookupName = "foobar")
    public String greet;
    public String anotherMember;
    @DynamicValue(lookupName = "primitive")
    public int primitiveNumber;
    @DynamicValue(lookupName = "boxed")
    public Integer boxedNumber;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        application.greet = "world";
        application.anotherMember = "Another member";
        application.primitiveNumber = 11;
        application.boxedNumber = 22;
        application.sayHello();
    }

    private void sayHello() {
        System.out.println(anotherMember);
        System.out.println("Hello " + greet);
        System.out.println(primitiveNumber);
        System.out.println(boxedNumber);
    }
}
```

**Mofified aspect targetting `int`/`Integer` field accessors only:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import de.scrum_master.app.DynamicValue;

@Aspect
@Configurable
@Component
public class DynamicValueAspect {
    @Pointcut("get(* de.scrum_master.app..*) && @annotation(dynamicValue)")
    public void isDynamicValue(DynamicValue dynamicValue) {}

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "isDynamicValue(dynamicValue)", returning = "field")
    public void getLocalized(DynamicValue dynamicValue, int field, JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        System.out.println("    " + dynamicValue);
    }
}
```

**New console log:**

```
Another member
Hello world
get(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.primitiveNumber)
    @de.scrum_master.app.DynamicValue(lookupName=primitive)
11
get(Integer de.scrum_master.app.Application.boxedNumber)
    @de.scrum_master.app.DynamicValue(lookupName=boxed)
22
```

BTW, I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29590025/1082681).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked like charm. 
1) Can I create a pointcut that supports both primitive and wrapper return type? 
Eg: @Pointcut("get(Integer de.scrum_master.app..*) || get(int de.scrum_master.app..*) && @annotation(dynamicValue)") 
2) Will the pointcut work if I just print the class variable without calling its getter?
Thanks again for the help you've already did. :)

Comment: Could you please look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991659/pointcut-get-expression-not-working-in-xml
Thanks in advance. You're the savior.

Comment: @YadvendraRathore, I have updated my answer so as to address your first question.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution. Your solution worked perfectly, but now I'm stuck at some other point. Have posted this question 5 days ago & got no answer. Could you please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991659/pointcut-get-expression-not-working-in-xml this question. Maybe it's just you who can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your method signature as follows:

```
@Around("isDynamicValue()")
public void getLocalized(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, DynamicValue dynamicValue) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(dynamic.lookupName());
}
```

I didn't quite understand if you also have problems with the pointcut. Here is an example that should work though

```
@Around("execution(@com.package.sample.DynamicValue * *(..)) && @annotation(dynamicValue)")
public void isDynamicValue() {}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying your concept to retrieve the annotation parameter but facing issue in retrieving in @around advice
@Pointcut("get(@com.util.DynamicValue java.lang.String com.sample.package.*.*)")
 public void isDynamicValue() {}<br>
@Around("isDynamicValue()")
 public String getLocalized(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,DynamicValue dynamicValue) throws Throwable 

It gives errror formal unbound in pointcut at 2nd argument in advice method

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: it gives error "formal unbound in pointcut" in 2nd argument of @Around advice

Comment: `execution()` is the wrong pointcut in this case because the OP wants to use `get()` so as to intercept member access.