# Pointcut get expression not working in XML

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aop, pointcut

I have a pointcut expression which is working fine when written in java but when written in xml gives error. Since my aspect is written in one project and it's jar is available in other project I have to provide it's mapping in the XML in other projects using the same aspect in JAR.
In Java:

```
@Pointcut("get(java.lang.String com.air.ghl..*) and @annotation(value)")
public void isDynamicValue(DynamicValue dynamicValue) {}

@Around("isDynamicValue(dynamicValue)")
public Object getDynamicString(DynamicValue dynamicValue, ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    System.out.println("    " + dynamicValue);
    return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
}
```

In XML:

```
<bean id="dynamicValueAspect" class="com.air.ghl.util.DynamicValueAspect"/>
<aop:aspect id="dynamicValue" ref="dynamicValueAspect">
    <aop:pointcut id="dynamicValueStringPointCut" expression="get(java.lang.String com.air.ghl..*) and @annotation(value)"/>
    <aop:around method="getDynamicString" pointcut-ref="dynamicValueStringPointCut"/>
 </aop:aspect
```

Error while server up:

```
Caused by: org.aspectj.weaver.tools.UnsupportedPointcutPrimitiveException: Pointcut expression 'get(java.lang.String com.air.ghl..*) && @annotation(value)' contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'get'
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.validateKindedPointcut(PointcutParser.java:522)
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.validateAgainstSupportedPrimitives(PointcutParser.java:437)
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.validateAgainstSupportedPrimitives(PointcutParser.java:412)
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.resolvePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:311)
at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:294)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:208)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:194)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getMethodMatcher(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:169)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.buildSafePointcut(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:187)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor.<init>(AspectJPointcutAdvisor.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
```

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously in your code you were using full-fledged AspectJ (maybe via LTW, load-time weaving). Then you are fine with `get()` pointcuts. The XML variant is obviously Spring AOP and as the error message says, as an "AOP lite" framework it does not support `get` among several other AspectJ pointcuts, see Spring manual, chapter on AOP, section [Supported Pointcut Designators](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators). It says:

> The full AspectJ pointcut language supports additional pointcut designators that are not supported in Spring. These are: call, get, set, preinitialization, staticinitialization, initialization, handler, adviceexecution, withincode, cflow, cflowbelow, if, @this, and @withincode. Use of these pointcut designators in pointcut expressions interpreted by Spring AOP will result in an IllegalArgumentException being thrown.

Comment: Thanks Kriegaex. Isn't there any way I can try this? I don't want to add same class to different projects.

Comment: Just read the AOP chapter and get acquainted with all options you have with Spring AOP and additional options you have with AspectJ in combination with Spring. If you want to use `get()`, there is no way around AspectJ. If you want to stick with Spring AOP, you need to refactor your pointcuts to intercept getter methods rather than field access.